# How to change the IP-address of a QEMU instance installed on ubuntu?

Tags: ip-address, qemu

I have installed two QEMU instances on my Ubuntu system, and both instances are currently configured with the same IP address. However, I need to establish SOME/IP communication between the two QEMU instances, so I want them to have unique IP addresses, to avoid confusion. To achieve this, I would like to change the IP address of one of the QEMU instances.

I tried editing the **01-netcfg.yaml** file with the command **sudo nano /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml**.

**At first the files contents were:**

network:

version: 2

renderer: networkd

ethernets:

```
enp0s2:       # Replace with your host machine's network interface name

  dhcp4: no
```

bridges:

```
br0:

  interfaces: [enp0s2] # Replace with your host machine's network interface name

  dhcp4: yes
```

**I did the following changes to the file:**

network:

version: 2

renderer: networkd

ethernets:

```
enp0s2:       # Replace with your host machine's network interface name

  dhcp4: no
```

bridges:

```
br0:

  interfaces: [enp0s2]

  addresses: [192.168.0.100/24]  # Example IP address: 192.168.0.100, subnet mask: 24 (255.255.255.0)

  nameservers:

    addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]  # Example DNS server IP addresses (Google DNS)
```

But these changes did not change the IP. Are there any other approaches I can try?